# Дискретность дробного числа

Tags: php, числа

Есть число, которое может содержать дробную часть. Необходимо проверить дискретность числа 0.5

Т.е.:

```
3 // удовлетворяет
4.5 // удовлетворяет
4.55 // не удовлетворяет
4.35 // не удовлетворяет
```

Есть идеи конечно, что-то типо:

```
    if (is_numeric($_POST['value']))
    {
        $x = $_POST['value'] * 10;
        $dr = $x - floor($x);
        if ($x%5==0 && $dr == 0)
        {}
        else
        {
            throw new CHttpException(400,"Кратность должна быть равна 0.5");
        }
    }
```

есть ли алгоритм полегче?

Comment: А 3.0000001 -- удовлетворяет?

Comment: > А 3.0000001 -- удовлетворяет?

нет, но я понял к чему вы клоните :) Если данное значение будет представлено во float как 3.0, то оно подходит, и в этом случае человек сам виноват что ввел его.

Comment: @IVsevolod а я не понял. Система счисления у нас двоичная. Значит 0.5 представляются точно -- одной единичкой в мантиссе. Но близкие к 0.5 значения могут получаться в результате вычислений. Так вопрос -- с какой точностью Вы хотите отнести (или не отнести) число к 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ещё можно так:

```
fmod($a / 0.5, 1.0) != 0
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fmod.php

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

А еще вроде и так можно:

```
if ($a/0.5-round($a/0.5)==0) echo "кратно";
```

Answer (score 0):

9.7 кратно (дискретно) 0.1 Тоесть 0.1 помещается в 9.7 ровно 97 раз.

Не работает:

```
fmod(9.7 / 0.1, 1.0); // => 0.99999999999999
```

Не работает:

```
9.7 / 0.1 - round(9.7 / 0.1); // => -1.4210854715202E-14
```

Не работает:

```
9.7 % 0.1; // => DivisionByZeroError
```

Сюрприз:

```
intVal(9.7/0.1); // => 96
```

Единственный рабочий вариант, что мне удалось сделать это через сравнение строк:

```
$a = 9.7;
$b = 0.1;
$p1 = round($a / $b); // => int 97
$p2 = $p1 * $b; // => float 97
$ok = (string)$a == (string)$p2; // => TRUE
```